# state maintaining variable which goes back to the previous state after a time

Tags: java, variables

Is it possible for a variable in java to revert back to its previous state after a time limit.For example:If I have a boolean variable say **x** which was initialized to **false** and later the value was changed to true.Is it possible for this variable to revert back to its original value (ie **false**) after a time limit.Can this be achieved without using a timer or are there any design patterns to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: Ya. Keep another boolean variable with name `prevValue` that keeps the previous value held by your `mainValue` field :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
class RevertingBoolean {
    private long timeToRevert = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private boolean value;
    private boolean defaultValue;

    void setDefaultValue(boolean value) {
        this.defaultValue = value;
    }

    void setRevertAfter(long revertAfter) {
        this.timeToRevert = System.currentTimeMillis() + revertAfter;
    }

    void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    boolean getValue() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > timeToRevert) {
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
            timeToRevert = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
RevertingBoolean myBool = new RevertingBoolean();
myBool.setDefaultValue(false);
myBool.setValue(false);
myBool.setRevertAfter(10000); // Revert value in 10 seconds

myBool.getValue(); // false
myBool.setValue(true);
myBool.getValue(); // true

// ... 10 seconds later ...

myBool.getValue(); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Find a small example of a class which keeps the state and based on the timeout it negates the state.
See this as a PoC. You might need to do some improvements for concurrent access or visibility if you want to use it in a multithreaded application.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    VolatileState volatileState = new VolatileState();
    System.out.println("initial: " + volatileState.getState());
    volatileState.setState(true, 5);
    System.out.println("valid  : " + volatileState.getState());
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("reset  : " + volatileState.getState());
}
```

The class which keeps the state for a given time.

```
class VolatileState {
    private long timeSet = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private long timeToLive = 0;
    private boolean state;

    /**
     * Keep the given state for <code>timeToLife</code> seconds.
     */
    void setState(boolean state, long timeToLive) {
        this.timeSet = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.timeToLive = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToLive);
    }

    boolean getState() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > timeSet + timeToLive ) {
            state = !state;
            System.out.println("state reset to " + state);
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, e.g., BooleanReverts, which has members for the new value, old value to which it reverts, and time to revert, and with setter methods that set up reversion. You probably want a separate thread to manage all the timers and execute callbacks to effect the reversion.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple generic class and a Test case with a boolean type (but you can use with any type) of a class that shoud match your requirements

```
package test;

public class TimeValueVar<T> {
    private T originalValue;
    private T currentValue;
    private long duration;
    private long creationTime;


    public TimeValueVar(T value, long duration) {
        originalValue=value;
        currentValue=value;
        this.duration=duration;
        creationTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        currentValue=value;
    }

    public T get() {
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis()-creationTime)>duration) {
            return originalValue;
        }
        return currentValue;
    }




}
```

here is the test case

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TesttimeBasedValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long duration =2000;
        TimeValueVar<Boolean> boolVal=new TimeValueVar<>(true,duration);
        System.out.println("original: " + boolVal.get());
        boolVal.set(false);
        System.out.println("before duration  : " + boolVal.get());
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(duration+1);
        System.out.println("after duration  : " + boolVal.get());

    }

}
```